# program not found on ssh server when running command locally

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, hpc

I am trying to run a script held on an ssh server, locally.

My command to do this is:

```
ssh -t myserver "cd Phd/script_dev ; ./hpcin.sh file.txt me@gmail.com ; bash"
```

where `hpcin.sh` is:

```
#!/bin/bash
sed "s/myfile/$1/g" < hpcrun.sh | bsub -N -u $2
```

which already exists on the server, and not on my local machine. However I get the following error:

`./hpcin.sh line 2: bsub: command not found`

However bsub does exist, and by including `;bash` at the end of my local command, I can see that I shh into the correct folder. So what I did is ssh in, then run `hpcin.sh` while inside the server......which works!

So I guess what I am asking is - how come my local command ssh's me into the correct folder on the ssh server, where it can find `hpcin.sh`, and yet cannot call a program that clearly exists on the server? I proved that `bsub` does exist by ssh'ing into the same folder, and running `hpcin.sh` with no problem.

Help!

Comment: Is `bsub` defined in one of your login files (`.bashrc`, `.bash_profile`)?

Comment: @tonchis - it wasn't but have added it  and dtill not working. i did this by by doing the following `$ which bsub
/opt/lsf/7.0/linux2.6-glibc2.3-x86_64/bin/bsub
` and then adding this to `~/.bashrc` and checking it's in there `$ echo $PATH
/opt/lsf/7.0/linux2.6-glibc2.3-x86_64/etc:/opt/lsf/7.0/linux2.6-glibc2.3-x86_64/bin:/opt/kusu/bin:/opt/kusu/sbin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/opt/intel/clck/1.6:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/share/centrifydc/bin:/opt/lsf/7.0/linux2.6-glibc2.3-x86_64/bin/bsub` where you can see in the last entry it is in there.

Comment: @tonchis - however if the first command I send is `/etc/profile;` then it works. so you are right that I need to load it first

Comment: You don't want the trailing 'bsub' on the path you add to $PATH.